# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'components') in pure JS app

Tags: javascript, web, frontend

I have an issue that I cant solve. Writing pure js application and then have a error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'components')
    at new Excel (Excel.js:4:31)
    `at Header._createSuperInternal` (Formula.js:3:1)
    at new Header (Header.js:3:1)
    at Excel.js:11:25
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Excel.getRoot (Excel.js:10:21)
    at Excel.render (Excel.js:19:26)
    at Module../index.js (index.js:12:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at startup:7:1
```

My code at Excel.js:

```
       export class Excel {
      constructor(selector, options) {
        this.$el = document.querySelector(selector)
        this.components = options.components || []
      }
    
      getRoot() {
        const $root = document.createElement('div')
    
        this.components.forEach(Component => {
          const component = new Component()
          $root.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', component.toHTML())
        })
    
        return $root
      }
    
      render() {
        this.$el.append(this.getRoot())
      }

}
```

at Formula.js for example i tried to render some text in pages, code:

```
        import {Excel} from '../excel/Excel'
    
    export class Formula extends Excel {
      toHTML() {
        return '<h1>Formula</h1>'
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your error in the code which create the Excel object `new Excel(selector,options)` or  `new Formula(selector,options)`- you miss `options` argument

Comment: const excel = new Excel('#app', {
  components: [Header, Toolbar, Table, Formula],
})

excel.render()

Thats how it looks. The place where i create Excel

Comment: try to use this construction of class definition: 
`class Class { constructor(props){ Object.assign(this, props); } ... }` and create instance `let object = new Class({ param1: value1, param2: value2 });`